# Pie time animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I Am building an app using query mobile, I have been struggling with this code for some time:

[JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/yikeze/1/edit?console,output)

What it does is to create multiple pie timers that will start when clicked.
The problem is when I reload the page the timers reset, I know that I somehow need to instantiate the timer with some id but since I have limited knowledge of javascript I can't figure it out, how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'change to another page and back again',
I take it that you reload the page?

You need to have a database (ex. mysql) set up so that
you can figure out when the time left when a user visit that page again.

1. User clicks the pie
2. Pie saves current_time and ending_time into db
3. User reloads the page
4. Page pulls the current_time and ending_time
5. Page generates the pie relative to the current_time and ending_time